# Can't hide navigation bar using only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on the Free Code Camp project for which you need to make a product landing page.

I have everything that I want already except for two things.

1. The navigation bar goes behind the hero header image
2. When the user scrolls down, I want the navigation bar to be hidden – it currently does not do this.

Here is my code:

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/** global classes styling **/

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 3px black solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 75px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  header {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 60vw;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
}

.logo>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .logo>img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

nav {
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 50px;
    transition: top 0.1s;
    /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
  }
  nav li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

nav>ul {
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  nav>ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

#hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#hero>h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#hero input[type="email"] {
  max-width: 275px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#hero input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}

#hero input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #hero {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}

#features {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#features .icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 125px;
  width: 20vw;
  color: darkorange;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  #features .icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

#features .desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 125px;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  #features .desc {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #features {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

#aboutOurApp {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#aboutOurApp>iframe {
  max-width: 560px;
  width: 100%;
}

#pricing {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

#aboutOurCompany {
  margin-top: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.product>.level {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.product>h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.product>ol {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.product>ol>li {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.product>button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.product>button:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #pricing {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .product {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer>ul>li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

footer>span {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #444;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.hero-image {
  /* Use "linear-gradient" to add a darken background effect to the image (photographer.jpg). This will make the text easier to read */
  background-image: url("https://collectivecloud.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/iphone-410324_1280-1024x682.jpg");
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 900px;
  width: 1920px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="https://collectivecloud.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/image-1-350x200.png" alt="Collective Cloud logo (This is really my company by the way ust in case)" />
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#aboutOurApp">About Our App</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <section id="hero" class="hero-image">
      <div class="full-width">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>Auto Build Websites</h1>
          <p>Best app out there
          </p>
          <p style="padding: -100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <p style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="container" id="features">
      <section id="features">
        <div class="grid" id="features">
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weather-2-4/100/Weather_Set-07-512.png" height="200px" width="200" />
          <div class="desc">
            <h2 style="color: #0ac0ed;">SEO Optimization</h2>
            <p>
              Increases the quality and quantity of website traffic by increasing the visibility of a website or a web page to users of a web search engine
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weather-2-4/100/Weather_Set-07-512.png" height="200px" width="200" />
          <div class="desc">
            <h2 style="color: #0ac0ed;">Responsive Design</h2>
            <p>
              Responsive web design is an approach to web design that makes web pages render well on a variety of devices and window or screen sizes.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">

          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weather-2-4/100/Weather_Set-07-512.png" height="200px" width="200" />
          <div class="desc">
            <h2 style="color: #0ac0ed;">24/7 Support</h2>
            <p>
              We provide 24/7 full support to our customers who are always looking to improve their business.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p style="padding: 30px;">
      </section>
      <section id="aboutOurCompany">

        <img src="https://collectivecloud.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/image-1-350x200.png" width="350" height="200" alt="image-1" title="image-1" padding:50px>
        <p>We at Collective Cloud, LLC offer a range of services that will improve your business and help your business have a better internet presence. We offer a pro website with features tailored to your business that will give you a competing edge in
          your industry.</p>
      </section>
      <p style="padding: 30px;">
        <section id="pricing">
          <div class="product" id="tenor">
            <div class="level" style="background-color: #3aa8fc;">Free App</div>
            <h2>FREE</h2>
            <ol>
              <li>Contains Ads</li>
              <li>Restricted Functionality</li>
              <li>No Social Media</li>
            </ol>
            <button class="btn">Select</button>
          </div>
          <div class="product" id="bass">
            <div class="level" style="background-color: #3aa8fc;">Paid App</div>
            <h2>$100</h2>
            <ol>
              <li>No Ads</li>
              <li>Full functionality</li>
              <li>Can Upgrade</li>
            </ol>
            <button class="btn">Select</button>
          </div>
          <div class="product" id="valve">
            <div class="level" style="background-color: #3aa8fc;">Pro App</div>
            <h2>$200</h2>
            <ol>
              <li>No Ads</li>
              <li>Premium Functionalities</li>
              <li>Code-Level Support</li>
            </ol>
            <button class="btn">Select</button>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="aboutOurApp">
          <div id="video" style="text-align: center;">
            <p style="padding: 30px;">
              <h1>Checkout How it Works</h1>
              <p style="padding: 90px;">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MWV45qb9nCQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="hero">
          <h1>Best Website Development App in the World</h1>
          <h2>Don't miss out on any updates!</h2>
          <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Subscribe Now" required />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Get Started" class="btn" />
          </form>
        </section>
        <footer style="align-content: center;">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          </ul>
          <span>Copyright 2020, Collective Cloud, LLC</span>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, read about [mcve], avoid adding all your code, add just the relevant to the question, as stated in the link I posted

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS add

```
position: relative;
left: -14px;
```

or just use

```
overflow: hidden;   //it won't show at all
overflow: auto;     //scrollbar will only show when content is more
```

Comment: in what part do i add it to?

Comment: in your nav bar that exceed the hero header page

Comment: Can you please add it to the code cuz I cant seem to get it to work :(:(